# code infinite loop cannot print only once

Tags: c++

hi I have this simple code to print out book word when i is equal 2

```
int i;
    for (i=0;i!=5;i++)
    {
        if(i=2)
        {
            cout  << "book";
        };

    }
```

i dont know why this code always looping even though I limit i to 5.

if I print i before if condition its printing this

```
0book3book3book3book3book3book3book3book3book3book3boo....
```

im using online compiler to compile this.

anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. Here is an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4f129ea1596a59e) of how clear your compiler can be in explaining logic errors right from the start.

Comment: `if(i==2)` !!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a goddamn typo.

Comment: Always use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` before asking questions.

Comment: You also have a stray semicolon after your if statement. You may want to remove it.

Comment: This would work:
int i;
    for (i=0;i!=5;i++)
    {
        if(i==2)
        {
            cout  << "book";
        };

    }

Answer (score 8):

```
if(i=2)
```

should be

```
if(i==2)
```

Classic mistake

Comment: thanks, my bad for not noticing it

Answer (score 6):

`if(i=2)` --> assignment operator

`if(i==2)` --> comparing. **Very** different.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(i=2)
```

is equivalent to

```
i = 2;
if(i != 0)
```

you need

```
if(i == 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah as Roger said what you have done is do an assignment within the if statement instead of a comparison.

```
if(i=2) //assignment
if(i==2)//comparison
```

personally when comparing a variable to a raw int etc I like to do the following:

```
if(2==i) //comparison no error
if(2=i) //attempt to assign to raw int :ERROR
```

Answer (score 2):

Instruction

```
if(i=2)
```

mean: assign value 2 to i and check if i!=0.

You had to do:

```
if(i==2)
```

Check if i is equal to value 2.

Simply syntax.